# Using Azure Resource Manager REST API

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to use Azure ARM REST API. Considering an example to create a Resource group, this is the API mentioned in azure documentation

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourcegroups/{resource-group-name}?api-version={api-version}
```

My code:

```
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxx',
    'Authorization': 'xxxxx',
    'Identifier' : 'xxxxx'
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
"location":"Central US"
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('xxxx.azure-api.net')
    conn.request("PUT", "/resourcegroups/resourcename?api-version=2015-01-01%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(response.status)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I am getting a 404 Error. Can you please help me in finding out where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't you forget the /subscriptions/{subscription-id} part in the URI that you have in the line from the documentation?

Comment: @miracledev as I'm aware that's what the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`parameter is

Comment: @MichaelB Are you sure that is applicable to the Resource Manager REST API? Isnt that a API Management feature?

Comment: @miracledev I made the presumption from the endpoint `azure-api.net` (and perhaps missed the question title!) so yes you are probably right that the OP needs the additional URI parameter

Comment: I'm confused as to where the APIM parameters come in.  If you're just calling the ARM API, you should be using https://management.azure.com as the base address, not xxxx.azure-api.net, and you would need to include the subscription as @miracledev said.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think there are some mistakes in your code as below.

1. According to [the package `httplib` API reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html), the REST API url should be split up into the `host`, `path` & `query string`(or `params`) as the arguments for the function `httplib.HTTPSConnection` & `conn.request`, as @miracledev's comment said. So the response status was 404 not found.
2. The HTTP request of the function `conn.request` also was missing for the [Common parameters and headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790546.aspx) & the [`location` required header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790525.aspx) of the REST API as `headers` that the `Authorization` header content be got from [authenticating Azure Resource Manager request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx).

[image]

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: Hi, I have changed my header and conn.request as you have mentioned. Now my header includes cotent-type,client_id, tenant_id and authentication_key. The conn.request is like this. conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.azure.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/rapidresource?api-version=2015-01-01%s" % params, "{body}", headers). But now its throwing 401 authorization error. Is there any other parameter that I should include in my header section?

Comment: @shwetha The headers should include the required elements that you can find in the REST API doc. The `client_id`, `tenant_id` and `authentication_key` are used for requesting the access token that be used in the header `Authorization`, please concern the doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx.

Comment: Ok so I did `pip install adal` and passed these parameters to get a access token. Then I used it in the header section. But its still throwing me a 401 error.

Comment: @shwetha For authenticating ARM in Azure SDK for Python, please see http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagementauthentication.html#using-service-principal. If you want to create a resource group using SDK, you can see http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html#create-resource-group.

Comment: @shwetha You can try to use the tool `Postman` to request these REST API and debug with the response information include the 401 error reson.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use msrest library instead of plain http, as it will do most of the work for you. For instance it will obtain appropriate access token.
It also handles polling properly.

I have some autogenerated Python REST examples here:

https://github.com/zikalino/azure-python-examples